# jQuery change CSS of div outside of Iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

Right now I am working an a simple script.

Let me first give you all the code that I have:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function SuperWebF1() {
        $("#outerdiv").css({"border":"2px solid #e39f9f"});
        alert('SportsDirect.bg: Моля, първо посочете желания от Вас цвят!');
    }
</script>
<div id="outerdiv">
    <iframe src="http://beta.sportsdirect.bg/checkout/onepage/" id="inneriframe" scrolling="no" target="_parent"></iframe>
</div>
```

The iframe contents this button:

```
<button type="button" class="button" onclick="parent.SuperWebF1();">Clickme</button>
```

So when the button is pressed into the iframe I want to change the CSS of the div that is holding the iframe.

Note that the jQuery code is called outside and before the iframe.

How can I make that or where is my mistake in my example?

Comment: Do you have access to the code inside and outside the iframe?

Comment: You cannot access the DOM outside the iframe from within it.

Answer (score 1):

Acessing the content of an iFrame with the content from outsite your server is a security problem called ["cross origin"](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) and is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

The following method would work in IE8 and above if you have access to both the iframe and the parent code:

In Iframe:

```
<button type="button" class="button" onclick="parent.postMessage("button_clicked", "http://parent-domain.com");">Clickme</button>
```

In Parent:

```
<script>
function SuperWebF1() 
{
    $("#outerdiv").css({"border":"2px solid #e39f9f"});
    alert('SportsDirect.bg: Моля, първо посочете желания от Вас цвят!');

}

// Create IE + others compatible event handler
var eventMethod = window.addEventListener ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent";
var eventer = window[eventMethod];
var messageEvent = eventMethod == "attachEvent" ? "onmessage" : "message";

// Listen to message from child window
eventer(messageEvent,function(e) {
  if (e.data == "button_clicked") {
      SuperWebF1();
  }
},false);
</script>
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage for security and other concerns